# Get list of deleted JIRA Issues using APIs

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I need to find a list of JIRA Issues that have been deleted. With the JIRA APIs I can only get the non-deleted JIRA Issues. There is no soft deleted flag returned in the API response.

Is there way to get a list of deleted JIRA Issues? Just the IDs will suffice. Are the Issue deletions exposed in the Events API?

Answer (score 1):

For Jira Server, you could try pull every issue and iterate through the number part of the key. Presumably if there is a missing number, the issue has been deleted (Or you don't have view permissions for it). Unfortunately this wont allow you to know more than its key.

Eg. TEST-1, TEST-2, TEST-5 would allow you to assume TEST-3 and TEST-4 have been deleted.

Comment: this is the strategy i am currently using. I was looking for a better approach....

Answer (score 0):

Jira Cloud has an Issue Deleted event you could try listening for
https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-questions/Re-Is-it-possible-to-be-notified-when-issue-is-deleted/qaq-p/1146155/comment-id/365013#M365013

I don't think there is an equivalent for on-prem Jira. I've scanned access logs before to find the REST calls to delete. But not had any luck with any other approach. So, not really

Comment: Thanks. Yes I am not seeing anything for the on-prem JIRA.